# Overflow css property still allows flex items to overflow until view resize happens

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a 2 columns layout in the flex container. Second column can be hidden, so the first one takes all the space available. The basic styles are:

```
.container {
   display: flex;
   width: 100%;
   
   // so that flex items don't overflow the container,
   // an alternative that works is to put `min-width: 0` on the column2
   overflow-x: scroll; 
}

.column1 {
   flex-grow: 1;
}

.column2 {
   width: 30%
}
```

The weird behavior that I observe is that it works on the initial load. Then I hide the second column, and make it appear again. But when it does, it overflows the container. Once I resize the view with Dev Tools or a browser window resizing, the content respects `overflow` property and doesn't overflow. See the image below.

[image]

Anybody knows why that happens?